# Double-clicking or opening a .sql file starts a new instance of Toad for oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

Whenever I am trying to open .sql files in TOAD  it is opening a new instance every time .My Job nature makes me to work on multiple .sql files at the same time ,and new instnace every time is not very helpful in this scenerio.

I have already looked everywhere and could not find anything related to this.Is there any solution for this

your help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you are talking about clicking on the file name in Windows navigtor, then that is a Windows issue, not Toad.  Toad is registered with windows to be the application used when clicking a .sql file.  So windows does just that -- launches an instance of Toad and passes the file name.  In reality, Windows doesn't know what Toad does.  It just knows to launch toad.exe when you click a file with the .sql extension

Comment: Right; modify the behavior so that Notepad (instead of TOAD) opens a .SQL file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! Is there any way  to open  multiple .sql files,just by clicking on them  in  one instance of TOAD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick responses.

I wanted to achieve a way, to open multiple SQLs  in the same session,which can be done in sql developer by just clicking on the .sql files.

I realized ,I can't do the exact same thing as SQL developer in TOAD,but there is a workaround by creating workspaces with all my SQLs I work on regularly into it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the files from within TOAD instead of using Windows Navigator
2. Drag and drop the files instead of double-clicking them
3. Navigate the menu to "View / Toad Options...", select "StartUp", and uncheck the box for "Allow multiple copies of Toad to be loaded". Click "Ok", then close and restart Toad.